# Continous, Non-Fourier, Trigonometric Approximation of the Floor Function

Tags: functions, trigonometry, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I would like to know a single (not piecewise) continuous approximation of $\mathbb{floor}(x)$ which gets sharper the more you increase a constant. I do not want a series like Fourier, but I do want something that uses trigonometric functions, as that is the only way this seems to be possible. Here is what I mean:
[image]

It may be possible to find an approximation of $\mathbb{frac}(x)$, $f(x)$, then do $x-f(x)$

Comment: To be precise, you're looking for a continuous function $f(x,a)$ with parameter $a$ such that as $a\to\infty$ you get $f(x,a)\to\lfloor x\rfloor$, is that right?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, that is accurate. I do not $a$ to deal with number of terms in summation, however.

Answer (score 1):

The best I could come up with (without using Fourier), were piecewise functions. If it just needs to continuous we can use straight lines like this:
$$
f(x,a) = \begin{cases}
ax - (a-1)n - \frac12 & x\in(n-\frac 1{2a},n+\frac 1{2a}) \\
n & x\in(n+\frac1{2a}, n+1-\frac1{2a})
\end{cases}
$$
for $n\in\mathbb Z$.

We can smooth it out with a trigonometric function if you want:
$$
f(x,a) = \begin{cases}
\left |\cos x\right|^a+n & x\in(n-\frac12,n) \\
n & x\in(n,n+\frac12)
\end{cases}
$$
Any S-shaped curve will do for the transition, really. To make it symmetric, we could use $\frac{1}{1+\exp(-\tan(ax))}$ (a composition of $\tan$ and the logistic function). Or we could base it on a bump function such as $\exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-(ax)^2}\right)$ with appropriate scaling and gluing-together.

Comment: Is it possible to write this as a single expression?

Comment: Only if I can use the floor-function...

Comment: Well, this is not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: I kind of figured, but it was my best shot. By the way, $-\cos(\pi(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)/2)^a+\lfloor x\rfloor$ is a smooth-looking curve converging to the floor function (I know I cheated).

Comment: Maybe you should try to specify in the question what sort of function you want, because my suggestions actually fit the description: "a continuous approximation of floor$(x)$ which gets sharper the more you increase a constant." I kind of figured you wouldn't like them, but they are continuous, and they have the continuous parameter $a$.